# router.routerState is undefined Angular 2.1 testing

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular2-routing

How can I test `route.navigate`? I need to check if changed route after button click.. Here is my test:

```
it('Should log in and navigate to dashboard', fakeAsync(inject([LoginService, Router, Location], (authService: LoginService, router: Router, location: Location) => {
        let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#login');
        spyOn(authService, 'login').and.returnValue(Observable.of(true));


        button.click();
        tick(1000);


        expect(component.loading).toBe(false);
    })));
```

I am using `angular 2.1`

Answer (score 1):

what you should do to test if `router.activate` is getting called is inject a mock router, so you can spy on `activate`.

take a look at this example by Joe Eames's using the Angular-provided `RouterTestingModule`: https://gist.github.com/joeeames/0ddcfe8f0576bc7651ae99e6b59e81ea

Comment: you would take his example and work from there...see how [the router gets injected](https://gist.github.com/joeeames/0ddcfe8f0576bc7651ae99e6b59e81ea#file-routing-test-L42)? you could then spy on the `activate` method of that router, since it is the router the application is using...make sense?